# ionic serve returning error in ionic 2 project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I don't use node too often and I'm going back to an ionic2 project that worked perfectly 2 years ago.  I run `ionic serve` now and get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:doorman dave$ ionic serve
> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
[ng] node[6131]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:627:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
[ng]  1: 0x10003a9d9 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ng]  2: 0x100039a13 node::AddEnvironmentCleanupHook(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(void*), void*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ng]  3: 0x10005f205 node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ng]  4: 0x100226d47 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ng]  5: 0x100225ff8 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<true>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ng]  6: 0x1002259c0 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ng]  7: 0x346a5b0cfb7d 
[ng]  8: 0x346a5b089e66 
[ng]  9: 0x346a5b10a480
```

I've been googling this for a few hours and no matter what I do I can't get `ionic serve` to work.  Any ideas?

UPDATE
I've added version info below

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.5.0
   Ionic Framework               : not installed
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : not installed
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : not installed
   @angular/cli                  : not installed
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 7.0.0
   NodeJS     : v11.0.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.5.0
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Could this be happening because it says ionic framework isn't installed? I've tried installing it but nothing seems to change the results of `ionic info`

Comment: can you post ionic version and cordova version info?   $ionic info

Comment: I added version info. Thanks @NagendraBadiganti

Comment: try to reinstall the node_modules. It should work. You can also update your ionic version to the latest using this website https://update.ionic.zone/

Comment: Thanks Nagendra, I tried reinstalling node modules and using update.ionic.zone, but I just have the same error. I ended up making a new ionic app and just copying and pasting all the code in.

Comment: I see. It worked for my case. I`m sure that MacOS have an issue with node-sass dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall ionic like explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/):

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
$ sudo npm install -g ionic
```

and after that in your project use:

```
$ sudo npm install
```

And finally run with

```
$ ionic serve
```